# Detect Meteor environment?

Tags: javascript, environment, detect, meteor

I would like to know how can we detect whether meteor is running in development or production environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [process](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/process.html#process.platform) for that, another approach is to use [fs](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/fs.html) and check a file which you put in your dir which is different depending on the environment your application is in.

I think the best approach would be to use `process.env` and checking out `COMPUTERNAME`.

Comment: I have not found the COMPUTERNAME key, but I have found process.env.NODE_ENV that seems to fit perfectly here!

Comment: @THpubs Avoid adding more code content to answers. Instead, post your own answer with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use "**meteor_runtime_config**.ROOT_URL"

This returns ROOT_URL environment variable.

It's a simplest way to detect environment.

You can set this value in .bash_profile, or .profile

```
export ROOT_URL=http://YOURDOMAIN.com
```